# How to change the mail domain server so it's not displaying IP? Changing example@127.0.0.1.com to example@domainname.com

Tags: unix, ubuntu-9.10

I'm kinda a noob as a server admin so please bear with me. I've installed postfix mail server and everything is working fine but the 'from' box is displaying name@IPaddress.com. I want to set it up so it displays domainname.com instead of IP. I just hope you know what I mean. My main.cf in postfix folder looks like this:

```
    # See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = mail.thevinylfactory
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mail.thevinylfactory.com, thevinylfactory, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
```

Can anyone help me with this one? If you need any more details please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Set your hostname correctly
   Read more here http://www.randombugs.com/linux/change-hostname-domainname-linux-system.html
   about changing domainname/hostname
2. Look what you have in `/etc/mailname` and modify accordingly
3. Don't forget about  `/etc/hosts` & reverse DNS.

After everything is in place, restart postfix.

Regards

Comment: Thanks mate! Just edited mailname and it works like charm now.

Comment: I'm Glad to hear that :)